# Crashing at ABRecordCopyValue

Tags: iphone, ios

Following is the method:

```
-(id)getValueForProperty:(NSUInteger) propertyId{
   if(personRec != NULL)
        return (id)ABRecordCopyValue(personRec, (ABPropertyID)propertyId);   
   }
}
```

I am calling above method as follow:

```
NSString *lastName = (NSString *)[self getValueForProperty:kABPersonLastNamePhoneticProperty];
//or
NSString *lastName = (NSString *)[self getValueForProperty:kABPersonLastNameProperty];

NSString *firstName = (NSString *)[self getValueForProperty:kABPersonFirstNamePhoneticProperty];
//or
NSString *firstName = (NSString *)[self getValueForProperty:kABPersonFirstNameProperty];

NSString *orgName = (NSString *)[self getValueForProperty:kABPersonOrganizationProperty];
```

but when I run the application in device it's showing that it's crashing in line

```
return (id)ABRecordCopyValue(personRec, (ABPropertyID)propertyId);
```

in what case this can crash?

Comment: Is `personRec` pointing to a valid `ABRecord` ?

Comment: I checked the nullability of the personRec and yes it should be pointing to the valid ABRecord. Logically it should be correct but how can I check programmatically the validity of the personRec?

Comment: By "valid" I mean it's pointing to a live object, not one that has been released or something. The debugger tells you. Also, you need to tell us how it "crashes". Do you get an exception ? If so, which ? What error does the debugger tell you ?

Comment: what kind of crash do you have? are u calling the method from the same thread in which you requested the record?

Comment: Actually I am not able to see this crash while debugging but I am seeing the crash when I disconnect the device from system and run the application. So only source of information is the crash file. This may be related to thread but I have no clues if object is expired or not.

Comment: Make sure not to release the address book before copying the value out of the record

Answer (score 0):

It might be that a *ABMultiValueRef* is returned for one of your propertyId when calling *ABRecordCopyValue*, but you try to stuff it in a NSString.

In that case what you should do (say you're trying to get the first email address and you're using ARC):

```
ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
int no = ABMultiValueGetCount(emails);
if ( no > 0 )
{
    CFStringRef emailRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, 0);
    NSString* email = CFBridgingRelease(emailRef);
}
```